# Board games and dice, landing on a specific number with dice rolls?

Tags: probability

I ended up with a complicated problem.

I want to know what the chance is if you have a board game that you will land on a specific tile assuming that you will continue until you pass that tile.

the chance of landing on tiles is not equal (although I assume the further you get in the game the more this should even out).

- landing on the first tile is a $1/6$ chance.
- landing on the second
  tile, throwing either $2$ or $1,1$ will give you a $1/6+1/36=7/36$ chance.
- 3rd gives, $3;1,2;2,1;1,1,1$ (roll a $3$, a $2$ and $1$ or three times a $1$),
  which equals to $1/6+2\times1/36+1/216=49/216$ chance.
- 4th tile,
  $4;1,3;3,1;2,2;2,1,1;1,2,1;1,1,2;1,1,1,1$ which gives
  $1/6+2\times1/36+1/36+3\times1/216+1/6^4=343/1296$ chance.
- 5th tile,
  $5;2\times(2,3);2\times(1,4);3\times(2,2,1);3\times(3,1,1);4\times(2,1,1,1);(1,1,1,1,1)$, which
  gives 
  $1/6+2\times1/36+2\times1/36+3\times1/6^3+3\times1/6^3+4\times1/6^4+1/6^5 =
     2401/7776$ chance.

As you can see it becomes more complicated to do this by hand the higher the number is. So I want to make a script (in matlab) to calculate this for up to a 100 or so tiles, where I know the chances of landing on each of those 100.

I have an idea how to get the 6th and 7th tiles
but after that I'm not that sure anymore.

I'm sure that up to the sixth tile you could multiply the previous chances by $1/6$, add them up and add $1/6$.
for the 7th tile I have a good idea (multiply the previous 6 by $1/6$ and add them up) but I need to verify this.

Any help and verification is greatly appreciated.

Also I might possibly look into situations where you have two dice and thus an uneven chance distribution.

Ps. Thanks AMD for the edit.

Ps.Ps the $771/2497$ is a numerical error from matlab since apparently when using rational format it only takes into consideration up to 8 digits. This means that $771/2497$ is so close to $2401/7776$ that it can't see the difference.

Also for those interested a crude matlab code is below

```
format rat
nd=6; %Has to be bigger than 1, highest number on die
n=100; %tiles on board
A=zeros(n,1);
A(1,1)=1/nd;

for ind=2:n
    if (ind <= nd)
       k=ind-1;
       A(ind,1)=1/nd;
       for t=1:k
           A(ind,1)=A(ind,1)+A(t,1)/nd;
       end       
    else
       k=ind-1;
       p=ind-nd;
       for t=p:k
           A(ind,1)=A(ind,1)+A(t,1)/nd;
       end        
    end
end

hold on
plot(1:50,A(1:50,1))

%display(A)
% format short
% display(A)
```

Comment: I would proceed recursively.  That is, if $p_n$ is the probability of getting to square $n$, we have $p_n=\frac 16 \times \left( p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}+\cdots + p_{n-6} \right)$ for $n>6$.

Comment: For future reference you will probably like [how the site allows posting with mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: 771/2497 cannot be correct for the 5th tile result; the denominator must be a divisor of $6^5$, but $2497$ is divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$.

Comment: Why not use a Markovian Chain? Seems easier than recursive solutions since it only involves matrix computations.

Comment: Because I have no idea what a Markovian chain is and I looked at it quickly, but found it a bit complicated. I can see the potential of it but still this was the easiest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea.

The recursion of $P_n$ (the probability that the tile $n$ will be landed on) is 
$$
P_n = \frac16(P_{n-1}+P_{n-2}+P_{n-3}+P_{n-4}+P_{n-5}+P_{n-6})
$$
with $P_0 = 1$ and for all $k>0$, $P_{-k}=0$.

This recursion can almost be solved in closed form.  The key equation related to it, obtained by assuming a solution of the form $x^n$, is 
$$
x^6 = \frac16(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)
$$
which has a root of $1$, two pairs of complex conjugate roots whose absolute values are about $0.73$ and $.68$, and a real root of about $-0.670$.

Using the values of $P_0$ and $P_{-k}$ for small $k>0$ to determine the coefficients in front of each of those $x^n$, one obtains

$$ \begin{array}{lllll}P_n = \frac27 + \frac17 \left[ (-0.670332)^n + (-0.375695-0.570175i)^n \\ + (-0.375695+0.570175i)^n  + (0.294195-.668367i)^n + (0.294195+.668367i)^n \right] \end{array}
$$

From this we can see that as $n$ grows very large, the probability of landing on any particular tile approaches $\frac27$.  One can "justify" this as follows:  The average step size is $3.5$ and the reciprocal of that is $\frac27$.

Notice that the real parts of those five roots (other than the root of value $1$) add up to $-\frac56$ and if you plug in $n=1$ you find that $P_1 = \frac27 - \frac17 \cdot \frac56 = \frac16$, as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but apparently last time when I typed out my response I forgot to actually post it.

I assume you meant $P_n = \frac{1}{6} \left( P_{n-1} +  P_{n-2} +  P_{n-3} +  P_{n-4} +  P_{n-5} + P_{n-6} \right)$ which I can completely understand and makes total sense I wrote a script for this in matlab.

What I find harder to see is how that turns in your equation and how the hell you solve such a high order degree equation?

Honestly I would love some extra explanation how you turned it into an equation with 1 variable and what tools you used to solve.

Comment: You are right about the $P_{n-6}$ term, I have editted that in now. To get the equation, one makes the ansatz that the solution is of the form $P_n = x^n$, and divides through by $x^{n-6}$. Adding coefficients gives one root being $x=1$; divide out the factor of $(x-1)$. The resulting quintic has only one real root; find by Newton's method. Finallly, apply the quartic formula. Then get the coefficients of each $x^n$ by setting $P_0=1,P_1=\frac16,P_{-k}=0$

Comment: Once again thanks again for all the help :)